# iOS Localized String in Chinese

Tags: ios, format, localizable.strings, chinese-locale

I'm trying to put chinese characters in a localized string file ( Localizable.strings ) but xcode can't compile it, it says it is in the wrong format. If I remove the chinese characters it compiles fine, what should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to put 16 bit characters into a file designed for 8 bit characters.  Check the encoding on your file and make sure it's capable of preserving the proper character set(s) you need.

Comment: I'm not good at file encoding, could you help me? I'm trying UTF 16 with BOM but it still doesn't compile, do you know what encoding I must use? thanks!

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079930/how-to-change-text-encoding-of-localizable-strings-file-in-xcode-4