# How to make git consider .strings files as text file instead of binary file

Tags: git

Every time we make changes to the **.strings** files (for iOS localization) from different branches, we will have conflicts.

The reason seems to be that git consider the **.strings** as binary files instead of text files. Sometimes it is a little annoying because git won't help merging the changes automatically, again, because they are considered as in binary format.

Is there any git settings that will force it to consider a file as text file.

I notice that both SourceTree and GitLab won't be able to tell that it is text file. But XCode itself will be able to show us the diff. Not sure this is related or not.

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Create a `.gitattributes` file at the root of your repo with this contents:

```
*.strings diff
```

More information: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes

Comment: @slawomir-jaranowski suggests `text` while you suggest `diff`; what is the difference?

Comment: Using `diff` will cause files of that type to be diffed using your default difftool

Comment: In case you want to add this as a global setting for your user (instead of committing to the project), you can run `git config --global core.attributesfile <path>` where the path can be something like `~/.gitattributes`

Answer (score 24):

None of the solutions worked for me, so I did some more research and at [this link](https://gist.github.com/sprhawk/2779208) I found out this:

- in your project main directory, create or edit a .gitattributes file adding this line:

  ```
  *.strings diff=localizablestrings
  ```
- in the .gitconfig file in your home directory, add these lines:

  ```
  [diff "localizablestrings"]
  textconv = "iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8"
  ```

This did the trick.

Comment: I think this should be marked as the correct answer. Only solution that made git diff work and show the changes clearly as readable text. For me, at least. Note that .gitconfig is in your home directly, .gitattributes is something you add to your project directory. This excellent post says so, but easy to gloss over (well, I did the first time!)

Answer (score 13):

After trying Jonathan or Slawomir's solution, I am still not able to see the diff properly. They are still being considered as binary file.

I finally figure out that the our **localizable.strings** file are not in UTF-8 encoding but in UTF-16 encoding. After changing the encoding back to UTF-8, it works fine.

Is it okay to change the encoding? Yes, it is. It is actually recommended by Apple to use UTF-8.

> Note: It is recommended that you save strings files using the UTF-8 encoding, which is the default encoding for standard strings files. Xcode automatically transcodes strings files from UTF-8 to UTF-16 when they’re copied into the product.
>
> [[reference]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html)

How do you know what encoding that file is? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255305/how-to-determine-encoding-table-of-a-text-file) for command line and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079930/how-to-change-text-encoding-of-localizable-strings-file-in-xcode-4) for Xcode:

```
file -I vol34.tex
```

[image]

See comments below, you may have to change the encoding of the file manually:

```
iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF8 file.strings
```

Comment: I tried to do this with Xcode 9.2 and it didn't actually change the file encoding. It only changed what the `.xcproj` file thought the file encoding was. Fixed with `iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF8 file.strings`.

Comment: @EdwardThomson lol. Thanks! But I guess I'll leave the accepted answer as it is for now. Jonathan's answer did help me at that time IIRC. If this answer ever gets more votes than that answer later, I'll change the green tick ;)

Comment: For me, converting to UTF-8 also did the trick. However, I am using `genstrings` which generates the file in UTF-16LE, so I need to convert it back to UTF-8 each time its run.

Further, converting the file to UTF-8 using both `iconv` and Xcode didn't work for me, I ended up using VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

Please add in your project root directory file `.gitattributes` with content:

```
*.strings  text
```

Now git will recognize your files `.strings` as text files.

Comment: @jonathan-brink suggests `diff` while you suggest `text`; what is the difference?

Comment: From manual:  Setting the text attribute on a path enables end-of-line normalization and marks the path as a text file. End-of-line conversion takes place without guessing the content type.

Comment: And: A path to which the diff attribute is set is treated as text, even when they contain byte values that normally never appear in text files, such as NUL.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my variant of the script I used on my mac. I need to convert all `.strings` files to utf-8 encoding, including the fact that some of them were already in utf-8. Run it from folder where your `*.lproj` directories are placed.

```
STRING_FILES=$(find . -type f -name '*.strings')
for f in $STRING_FILES; do 
  ENCODING=$(file -I $f)
  if [[ $ENCODING == *"utf-16le"* ]]; then
    iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF8 $f > $f.1; 
    mv -f $f.1 $f
  fi
done
```

The idea of it was taken from Yuchen Zhong's answer

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that `SourceTree` is not able to diff english localization file only, the others were fine. So it looked like something was wrong in that file only.

I've replaced the english one with some other random `Localized.strings` file which were `SourceTree` diffing ok, copied english translations over, commit and voila - any new change was properly showed by `SourceTree`.

Remember you have to commit and see if it's working since you have to compare fixed one against fixed one.

Comment: Thanks @Viktor Kucera, that worked. I tried the others also but no luck there.

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way to do this was to use iconv to convert to UTF8, the other stuff does not work for viewing diffs in github.

```
iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 path/to/localization/en.lproj/Localizable.strings > temp.strings
mv temp.strings path/to/localization/en.lproj/Localizable.strings > temp.strings
```

Then commit and merge your changes.  *Subsequent* diffs will be shown properly.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions on this page
https://gist.github.com/asmallteapot/11227602

You don't have to convert your .strings files to UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

No need for .gitattributes and .gitconfig files in my case!

Simple steps you need to do:

1. Open currently available .strings file and copy all of it content
2. Open terminal type `nano <path/to/your/file/Localizable.strings>` - you can drag and drop file to terminal after typing `nano`  - **don't press return yet**
3. Remove file to trash (to save it in case of failure)
4. Go back to terminal and press return
5. Paste clipboard content to terminal
6. Press `control+x` and `y` to save the file
7. Repeat for .strings files in your project
8. Enjoy diff on your .strings files!